# Run bash script from GitHub with curl

Tags: linux, bash, github, curl

I want to run a script from GitHub with curl, and I can do this easily with:

```
# This is safe to run but will add a few lines to .bashrc, .vimrc, .inputrc to add some configuration options.
# Please check the project before running:
# https://raw.github.com/roysubs/custom_bash/
# But this is just to illustrate the point, bash shell script on GitHub, and how to use curl to pipe it to bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roysubs/custom_bash/master/custom_loader.sh | bash
```

I have a few problems with this however that I was hoping for some help with:

- Firstly, the script always runs unattended, ignoring all `read -e -p` statements to take input from the console. I'd appreciate if there is a better way to run the script such that it does not do this. Other methods to do this would be great.
- Secondly, I used git.io to shorten the above url to https://git.io/Jt0fZ but I can never get the above `curl` method to work using this. i.e. `curl -s https://git.io/Jt0fZ | bash` Does anyone know why this fails and for a workaround to use the shortened url to execute the remote script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Firstly" is more complex, but you might try a temporary shell script without using pipe.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roysubs/custom_bash/master/custom_loader.sh >tmp.sh

bash tmp.sh
```

Your "Secondly" question is very easy to explain, when you do `curl -s https://git.io/Jt0fZ`, we get a Redirect 302, here is hints:

We try to get headers only from the server:

`curl --head https://git.io/Jt0fZ`

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Cowboy
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 25 Apr 2021 14:24:43 GMT
Status: 302 Found
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roysubs/custom_bash/master/custom_loader.sh
Content-Length: 0
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Runtime: 0.003242
X-Node: 69d60833-56c5-4364-94c1-6f0c5b12863f
X-Revision: 392798d237fc1aa5cd55cada10d2945773e741a8
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

We see `HTTP/1.1 302 Found` and `Location: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/roysubs/custom_bash/master/custom_loader.sh`, not the real content of the latter.

So bash gets empty script to run, by default, curl does not do a second call to the new location, as does graphic webbrowsers usually do.

But you can do this to overcome the default:

```
curl -L https://git.io/Jt0fZ | bash
```

man curl gives this:

> -L, --location
> (HTTP) If the server reports that the requested page has moved to a different location (indicated  with
> a  Location:  header  and  a 3XX response code), this option will make curl redo the request on the new
> place.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone Yes thanks, i've added this at the end.

Comment: This is great, thanks. I've been scratching my head about these for quite a long time. For (1), `curl [bla] > tmp.sh ; bash tmp.sh` should work fine as you say, but is two commands. If there is no way around this, I can work with that of course (but great if someone knows a one-step solution). For (2), I see that the `-L` option works great (`curl` has so many options that my head breaks whenever I look at them!) 